How to regulate two way serial communication between python and arduino?
My question is kind of general, so I haven't included any code here. I am working on a project to control hardware and read sensors with an arduino board via a Python/tkinter interface on a PC. The idea is for the PC to be able to send serial commands to the arduino to manipulate hardware and to simultaneously transmit sensor data back from the arduino to the python script.
I have a working code that allows for the hardware communication as well as sends back updates every second from the sensor to the PC. It works fine until... an outbound command overlaps with an inbound sensor bit in which case it freaks out and freezes.
What is the general school of thought on how to regulate two way communications to deconflict incoming and outgoing serial communications?
I'm like brand new to python so I'd appreciate the most basic or simple (easy for a human to understand) version.
Thanks!

If the comport in your machine supports full duplex, then both incoming and outgoing can be performed at the same time.  However you need to perform them in separate threads.  The reading task should be executed in a child thread and sending task should be executed in the main thread.

@acw1668 - Thanks for that - do you happen to know of any simple examples of doing the dual threads?

Since the amount of data going back and forth will be very low overall, I may have gotten away with this 'hack' job. Instead of messing with the complexity of python serial communications, I edited the Arduino IDE to only transmit data if the port == 0 (free) and to put in a 50 ms buffer after sending a packet to help stabilize the communications.
>      int sensorValue = analogRead(A5);   
>          if (Serial.available() == 0) {
>              Serial.println(sensorValue);
>              delay(50);
>              }

